User sends funds to wrong chain
I want to know what it would take for the following scenario:

One of our users deploy a Safe using our app. The user deploys it in the ETH mainnet.
From a different Wallet, let's imagine Matamask, the user sends funds to the recently deployed Safe but sends it over the wrong network (let's imagine over Tron).

It is important to note that the Safe was not created from the Safe{Wallet} UI and it is a Safe4337 created programatically.
Is there any way the user can recover those funds? If so, what would the process be like?
Thanks!

Yes, they can be recovered.
Safe addresses are deterministic, so, you can deploy the safe on a different chain on the same address.
Official Resource - https://safe.mirror.xyz/bYaIiFzeP70K7KYzk_6yqqoFyTfmc-PiTVBB4lnH654

Updated my question! It doesn't let me do it by following the instructions in the link provided
